# Remove unwanted spaces between angle brackets

Tags: vim, whitespace

first but not least post here. I’d like some help with repetitive tasks that I’m performing at job right now. There are: How can I substitute in Vim a way to remove unwanted spaces within angle brackets from a mail list? Unfortunately, I couldn’t find out a clever way to deal with, I struggled a lot using `\zs` and `\ze` features, lookahead lokbehind regex but without a satisfactory solution. There are a sample:

```
Bilbo Baggins <bilbo.  baggins @ middleearth.net>; Galadriel < galadriel  @middleearth.net  >; Daeron < daeron@.middleearth.net >; Gandalf <  gandalf @middleearth.net>; Thorin II Oakenshield  < thorin.oakenshield  @ middleearth.net >; Aragorn < aragorn @ middleearth.net
```

And removing unwanted spaces will result in:

```
Bilbo Baggins <bilbo.baggins@middleearth.net>; Galadriel <galadriel@middleearth.net>; Daeron <daeron@.middleearth.net>; Gandalf <gandalf@middleearth.net>; Thorin II Oakenshield  <thorin.oakenshield@middleearth.net>; Aragorn <aragorn@middleearth.net
```

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Comment: Take a look at this http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a missing `>` at the end of your sample or not but the command below should work anyway:

```
:s/<.\{-\}\(>\|$\)/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\s','','g')/g
```

Comment: happy for that :) ! you can approve it so you close the question.